# Slumdog millionaire (9)

Tags: knowledge, computer-science

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about the 16.000 Euro question:

> The 16.000 Euro question brought up my area of expertise.  I was familiar
>   with the first technical term mentioned in the question, but its second
>   technical term seemed somewhat obscure.  I noticed that all the answers
>   were consecutive powers of two and that they were listed in increasing
>   order as well.  I figured that programmers and computer scientists usually
>   enjoy play-of-words, and after some thought I hesitatingly chose B.

***What was the 16.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Comment: We sure do love wordplay Q: What are you waiting for? A: 2 B: 4 C: 8 D: 16

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question was:

> "How many bits make a nibble?"

Justification:

> The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) says: The term "nibble" originates from its representing 
>  "half a byte", with "byte" a homophone of the English word "bite". 
>  Computer scientists enjoy the play-of-words with biting and nibbling.
>
>
>  Jamal says: "I was familiar with the first technical term mentioned 
>  in the question, but its second technical term seemed somewhat obscure." 
>  The term "bit" is very common, while the term "nibble" is not so
>  well-known and somewhat obscure.

Then the four answers were:

> A. $~~~~~2$
>  B. $~~~~~4$
>  C. $~~~~~8$
>  D. $~~~16$

Answer (score 5):

The question and the answers:

> How many bytes go in a kibibyte? 
>  A. 512 
>  B. 1024 
>  C. 2048  
>  D. 4096 
>  
>  There are some variations possible: 
>   - How many bits go in a kibibyte? 
>  - How many bits go in a mebibyte? 
>  - How many bytes go in a mebibyte? 
>  
>  Answers are the corresponding powers of 2 of course.

Justification:

> kibi is a wordplay on kilo and binary, and mebi is a wordplay on mega and binary. 
>  Therefore this answer does statistify the wordplay requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answers were:

> binary, quadral, octal, hexadecimal

The question might be:

> Which number system is not commonly used by programmers?

Comment: How does this statistify: *I was familiar with the first technical term mentioned in the question, but its second technical term seemed somewhat obscure.* ?

Comment: @wythagoras Because programmers don't use a quadral number system, but commonly use the other three.

Comment: But that are the terms in the answers, not the terms in the question. But I guess it is a reasonable answer, as that might be open to interpretation whether the terms in the answer count.